# pending when starting a container on remote host

Tags: docker

I have already configured remote api for docker in my server.

```
$ ps -ef |grep dockerd
root      5191     1  0  5월08 ?      00:01:41 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243
```

When I run a container in a Jenkins container running in my server,
The container is pended after creating the container.

[Execute Shell]

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://10.254.239.53:4243
docker run -it --rm ubuntu:18.04 ls
                                   <--- pending and display nothing
```

The result of `docker ps -a` in my server

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
609198e3928d        ubuntu:18.04                 "ls"                     8 seconds ago       Created                                                                lucid_curran
```

When I execute the same command with "-d" option, it is ok. But useless.

[Execute Shell]

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://10.254.239.53:4243
docker run -d ubuntu:18.04 ls
```

When I run the same command in my server, executed correctly.

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:18.04 ls
bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: From your remote host, are you able to talk to your server? `telnet 10.254.239.53 4243` Is it connecting from your remote host?

Comment: Looks like this is the case when you are trying to access host machine from inside of container using IP address . This require some additional network configuration.

Comment: @Thilak, I can execute some commands such as "docker ps -a", "docker build", ...

Comment: Can you execute `DOCKER_HOST=... docker run -v/:/host busybox cat /host/etc/shadow`?  Can _anyone_ who can reach the host do this?  Can you _change_ the file, say, to reset root's password?  I would remove remote Docker network access immediately, and consider the possibility the host is compromised.